Conceptual diagram in LaTeX
How can I write the following conceptual diagram in LaTeX?
I am not sure whether it is common to use TikZ for this purpose or if there are other methods available.
In the box □, I want to write some brief statement of mathematics like 'has solution on $\Bbb{Q}_p$ for all $p$ : prime  and on $\Bbb{R}$.

I tried the following code, but it is broken.
 \usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{amssymb} % For \Bbb
 
\begin{tikzpicture}

 % Draw boxes 
\node[draw, rectangle, align=center] (box1) at (0,0) {has
 solution on $\Bbb{Q}$}; 
\node[draw, rectangle, align=center] (box2) at
 (5,0) {has solution on $\Bbb{Q}_p$ for all $p$ : prime\\ and on
 $\Bbb{R}$.}; 
\node[draw, rectangle, align=center] (box3) at (10,0)
 {\Sha evaluates its failure};
 
% Draw arrows 
\draw[->] (box1) -- node[above,midway] {always holds}
 (box2); 
\draw[->] (box2) -- node[above,midway] {not always hold}
 (box1);
 
 \end{tikzpicture}


Here's a list of your new friends: a) https://tikz.dev/ , b) \node{}; , c)  anchor , use a  .  for polar notation, d) library arrows.meta . Give it a try and post your code here ... before the question gets closed ...

Unrelated: Note that \Bbb{...} is just for backwards compatability use \mathbb{...}, plus it should give you a warning in the log.

Don't know if this one comes close to your intention.
Changes made:

put a few missing lines

summarized your options as a style bx

made height equal

changed arrow tip

hat to replace unknown \Sha by \psi

for the arrows it was better to make them curved by replacing -- with to[in=,out=]


Hope this helps a little.
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb} % For \Bbb
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
 
\begin{document}
 
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    bx/.style={draw, rectangle, align=center,   % your options
                minimum height=12mm,            % equal height
              },
    >={Stealth},    % different arrow tip
 ]

    % Draw boxes 
    \node[bx] (box1) at (0,0) {has solution on $\Bbb{Q}$}; 
    \node[bx] (box2) at (5,0) {has solution on $\Bbb{Q}_p$ for all 
                                $p$ : \\prime and on $\Bbb{R}$.}; 
    \node[bx] (box3) at (10,0){$\psi$ evaluates its failure};
     
    % Draw arrows 
    \draw[->] (box1) to[out=30,in=150]  node[above] {always holds} (box2); 
    \draw[->] (box2) to[out=210,in=330] node[below] {not always hold} (box1);

 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


P.S.: Here's an example how you can

draw a diagram with class standalone
include its pdf via package graphicx


Cool. Thank you for your beautiful answer. I really appreciate it.

How do I draw two arrows in a diagram so that it starts from the middle of a box and extends horizontally to connect two boxes?

A few things to know: 1) nodes are placed at their center by default, i.e. if it adjusts to longer or shorter text, it will do so around its center point; 2) \draw (A) -- (B); connects nodes named A and B, i.e. at their center coordinates, also center-to-center; 3) IF your nodes are placed at the same y-coordinates, your intended result is just a consequence. However, the interior lines are almost never visible. // Same with my to-command: starts at center with outgoing angle (out=...), ends in other center at input angle given. // Does this answer your comment?

To add I tried separating your linear arrows in y direction using e.g. ([yshift=4mm]box1) , but that gave a mess for some reason. That's why I went for the curved ones.

Aiming to minimize the vertical space used in the diagram as much as possible (ideally, replacing the two arrows with a single horizontal arrow moving back and forth between the boxes, and ensuring that the text written above doesn't extend too high, making the total vertical space occupied by the diagram exactly equal to the height of the boxes themselves). Would this be difficult to achieve? If possible, I'd like to see a version of the code that accomplishes this.

\draw[<->] (A) —(B); draws a line with arrow tips at both ends. Find plenty of examples in tikz.dev / pgfmanual.

@BrauerManinobstruction If you load the positioning library (\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning} then you can say e.g. \node (box2) [right=25pt of box1.east] {box2 text}; to make more space horizontally between the nodes, which will give you space for a label between them if that's how you want to arrange things.

Here is a possibility with tikzcd.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd, amssymb, amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[cells={nodes=draw}, column sep=1cm]
\parbox[c][10mm]{4cm}{\centering has solution on $\mathbb{Q}$}\arrow[r, Rightarrow, shift left=5pt, "/"marking]
& \parbox[c][10mm]{4cm}{\centering has solution on $\mathbb{Q}_p$ for all $p$ : prime and on $\mathbb{R}$.}\arrow[l, Rightarrow, shift left=5pt]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}

